# Ajax response from php does not display received data as collapsible - jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I was expecting the below results to be displayed in collapsible fashion in html page but it would display the result without that in just plain fashion ?

I am suing `data-role="collapsible"` still it would not display it ?

php (updateProjectsCreated.php)

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

      echo "<div data-role=\"collapsible\"> " ;

         echo "<B> UniqueAdvertisingCode = '".$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode']."' </B>";
         echo "<B> AdvertiserName =  '".$row['AdvertiserName']."' </B>";
         echo "<B> Title = '".$row['Title']."' </B>";


         echo "<br><hr>";

      echo "</div> " ;

  }
```

javascript

```
function updateProjectsCreated(){


var email="xyz@gmail.com";

$.post("php/updateProjectsCreated.php",  

   { email:email}, function (data,status){
      $("#showeditdashboard").html(data);

   });

}
```

html

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page">

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

     <div id="showeditdashboard">  </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using jqm 1.4, change

```
$("#showeditdashboard").html(data);
```

To

```
$("#showeditdashboard").html(data).enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... any idea when i should use it specifically and why ?

Comment: To enhance any content added dynamically (after `mobileinit` event) we always call `.enhanceWithin()` on that parent of the new content.